# What is the fastest way to sample from multiple Metal textures?

Tags: ios, metal

I am working on some tricky Metal logic and I am wondering if anyone knows the fastest approach to read from multiple input textures in a Metal fragment shader (with the catch that this has to work on an A7 processor so no Metal2 features please).

```
fragment half4
fragmentShader(RasterizerData in [[stage_in]],
               texture2d<half, access::read> c0Texture [[ texture(0) ]],
               texture2d<half, access::read> c1Texture [[ texture(1) ]],
               texture2d<half, access::read> c2Texture [[ texture(2) ]],
               texture2d<half, access::read> c3Texture [[ texture(3) ]],
               constant RenderTargetDimensionsUniform &rtd [[ buffer(0) ]])
{
  ushort offsetGroup = ...;

  half4 inHalf4;

  // Choose from 1 of N textures

  switch (offsetGroup) {
    case 0: {
      inHalf4 = c0Texture.read(blockRoot);
      break;
    }
    case 1: {
      inHalf4 = c1Texture.read(blockRoot);
      break;
    }
    case 2: {
      inHalf4 = c2Texture.read(blockRoot);
      break;
    }
    case 3: {
      inHalf4 = c3Texture.read(blockRoot);
      break;
    }
  }

  ...
```

I attempted to optimize this logic using code like the following, but it was way slower.

```
   texture2d<half, access::read> arr[16];
   arr[0] = c0Texture;
   arr[1] = c1Texture;
   arr[2] = c2Texture;
   arr[3] = c3Texture;

   inHalf4 = arr[offsetGroup].read(blockRoot);
```

Is there some other approach that would work and give good performance when a number of input textures need to be read from like this?

Update: After looking at Ken's comment, I tried a simplified approach that uses the blit command encoder to copy each texture's data into a single texture with a slice offset in the Y axis. This modification cut 35ms off the shader execution time and is a big win!

```
fragment half4
fragmentShader(RasterizerData in [[stage_in]],
               texture2d<half, access::read> inTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
               constant RenderTargetDimensionsUniform &rtd [[ buffer(0) ]])
{
  ushort slice = ...;

  half4 inHalf4 = inTexture.read(blockRoot + ushort2(0, slice * sliceHeight));
```

Comment: How "dynamic" is the set of textures that you're using with this? In particular, could you build a 2D array texture instead of a bunch of 2D textures? (I'd suggest using an array of textures, but that's not available given your constraints.)

Comment: I read about 2D textures in the Apple docs, but that appears to be a Metal2 only feature. The code has to support the A7 processor to cover all 64 bit devices.

Comment: No, 2D array textures are not Metal 2-only. Arrays of textures are, but that's a different thing. 2D array textures are textures of type `MTLTextureType2DArray` in app code. They are represented using `texture2d_array<...>` in Metal shader code.